# C++.Вводится последовательность целых чисел(0 – конец последовательности)

Tags: c++

Вводится последовательность целых чисел(0 – конец последовательности). Определить, содержит последовательность хотя бы два одинаковых числа подряд.
C++

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в чем проблема? Вот план действий, чтобы решить:

Создайте массив на N элементов и заполните его, где N любое натуральное число (можно ввести с клавиатуры или создать константу)

```
int *arr = new int[n]
```

Потом циклом пройдите от 0 до N - 1

```
for(size_t = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {}
```

И проверяйте свою проблему

> содержит последовательность хотя бы два одинаковых числа подряд. C++

```
// Ваша логика в цикле
```

Если количество изначально неизвестно элементов

```
#include <vector>
```

Ввод будет таким

```
std::vector<int> arr
int tmp
while (std::cin >> tmp) {
    arr.emplace_back(tmp)
}
```

Получить размер можно будет с помощью функции `arr.size()`

Comment: А `n` откуда взять?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy исправил ответ

Comment: Я неясно выразился. Суть задачи в том что `n` заранее неизвестен. Если нужно все числа сохранить, то ответ - `vector`. В этой задаче хранить все числа не надо, ответом должен быть обновляющийся статус, который решает задачу на лету. Не обижайтесь, но вы предлагаете негодное средство для решения не той задачи.